# No body in outlook email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to get the body and head of an email upon receiving it in outlook. I am using the `NewMailEx` event handler to manage all emails that are coming in.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oNS         As NameSpace
Dim oFolder     As MAPIFolder
Dim oNewMail    As MailItem
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set oNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oNewMail = oFolder.Items.GetFirst

Set Msg = oNS.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
MsgBox Msg.Body

End Sub
```

This function is being called successfully, and I can get the header of the email by using:

```
MsgBox Msg
```

But when I try to use `Msg.Body` nothing is displayed in the `MsgBox`. Additionally, when I use `Msg.HTMLBody` I can see the html in the `MsgBox`, but still there is nothing in the  tag.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What shows up in the locals window for Msg? This code works fine for me. Also, just a comment but the olApp variable is not needed here.  What do you mean there is nothing in the tab?

Comment: It comes up blank, but I actually just figured out what the problem was a second ago. I will submit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out myself.

Because the email that I am working with is IMAP, only the subject line is downloaded from the server until the email is clicked, then downloading the body.

I was able to access the body of the email by first accessing the subject line beforehande like so:

```
Set Msg = oNS.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
MsgBox Msg
MsgBox Msg.Body
```